# Why does OpenSSL need the private key to revoke a certificate?

Tags: openssl, certificate-revocation

> openssl ca -revoke signed/0A.pem -config caconfig.cnf

What does this do which requires the CA's private key? Does it do anything except updating index.txt?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a bug of OpenSSL (at least in version 1.0.1c); precisely, a bug of the command-line "ca" option handling. If you look at the `apps/ca.c` source file in [OpenSSL source code](http://www.openssl.org/source/), you may see that the `MAIN()` function begins by parsing the command-line options, then reads the configuration file, then does this:

```
    /*****************************************************************/
    /* report status of cert with serial number given on command line */
    if (ser_status)
    {
         /* some stuff */
         goto err;
    }

    /*****************************************************************/
    /* we definitely need a private key, so let's get it */

    if ((keyfile == NULL) && ((keyfile=NCONF_get_string(conf,
            section,ENV_PRIVATE_KEY)) == NULL))
            {
            lookup_fail(section,ENV_PRIVATE_KEY);
            goto err;
            }
    if (!key)
            {
            free_key = 1;
            if (!app_passwd(bio_err, passargin, NULL, &key, NULL))
                    {
                    BIO_printf(bio_err,"Error getting password\n");
                    goto err;
                    }
            }
    pkey = load_key(bio_err, keyfile, keyform, 0, key, e,
            "CA private key");
```

Which means that the code will recognize the special case of checking on the revocation status of a certificate (command-line option `-status`), which of course does not need the CA private key, but will otherwise *insist* on loading the CA private key, whether it will be actually needed or not.

In particular, *revoking* a certificate, in the context of this tool, means marking it as revoked in the `index.txt` "database" of issued certificate, which does not use the CA private key. What uses the CA private key is signing the CRL (which informs the rest of the world that the certificate is really revoked), but the `-revoke` command-line option does not trigger that (it is the `-gencrl` option which implies issuance of a new CRL).

**Summary:** "`openssl ca -revoke`" implies reading the CA private key for no good reason at all. Feel free to patch the tool from its source code, and possibly submit the patch to the OpenSSL maintainers.

Comment: how interesting...

Answer (score 4):

The private key of the CA is needed because the revocation must be signed by the CA. Else it would be possible that the revocation is done by any entity.

Comment: I believe you are wrong (but I'm not shure). When i generate my CRL after revoking certificates, i do not see any difference between certificates that are revoked with the above command and certificates that are revoked by editing index.txt in a text editor. What do you mean is is signed when using the above command?

Comment: The CA private key is needed to generate the CRL (which is what @Uwe says) but the "-revoke" option does not imply a CRL generation; it just marks the certificate as "to be included in the next CRL, whenever this happens".

Answer (score 2):

Uwe Plonus is right. The CA always provides a revocation-list (**CRL**) in wich all revoked certificates are listed by their serial number and other information like the datetime when a crt was revoked.

See http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/crl.html# for further information.